# finding the codec of video file using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

In my application, i want user to upload **audio/video** files using,

```
<input type="file">
```

But i want to allow files having **h.264** codecs. So if user uploads a file with some other codecs even with the same extension, i need to show a message.

From the file object uploaded by user, i can get file type (like video/mp4), but i want to make sure that files only with h.264 codecs are uploaded. Unfortunately, i could not find anything to get the codec of video file being uploaded. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a note: users can easily break client-side validation and upload just anything. So you should do both client-side and server-side validation of codecs (if the former is even possible).

Comment: Have you tried using Blobs?
I don't know it it's possible but looking at:
[this](https://www.inkling.com/read/javascript-definitive-guide-david-flanagan-6th/chapter-22/blobs) and [this](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/06/05/working-with-files-in-javascript-part-5-blobs/) makes me think you can create a blob from binary data and request the blob.type.